# Restore Database on Different Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have backup (.bak) on one server and I want to restore the database on other server on Lan.. My concern is that when I run restore by connecting to remote sql server then it tries to find the .bak file on the remote server, but actually file resides on the server from which I am connecting to the remote server.

Is there some way around to this problem that I can restore database without copying the file on the remote server??

Comment: What kind of database do you use?

Comment: I am using microsoft sql swever

Comment: The operation is performed by the remote server - it doesn't pull any information through the connection you've established - the file has to be accessible, via file access methods, to the user account running the remote server, and from that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MS SQL Server you can map network drive or use system share. [Detailed info](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1126/sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-network-drive/).

Comment: Yes, but it will be not backup/resrote and it will be require network connection to the other database server (not file): replication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) and log shipping (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187016.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of using a .bak, run a dtsx to export all the data in your database. Just create the schema on the server your going to send the data. Right click on the origin database -> tasks -> export data.

This is just an alternative, I hope its of any use.

Cheers.